# OGRE - Multiple windows - render window and menu window

Tags: ubuntu, ogre

I am working with OGRE 1.7. I would like to make an application with two windows, the first one renders a scene (a bunch of 3D points) and second one must present a set controls (buttons, dragdown menus, labels etc). I am currently using SDKTrays for organizing the buttons, but since there are lot of controls they are cluttering the scene. I would like to organize them in a separate view.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Ogre ? I wasn't able to figure it out from the OGRE tutorials. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ogre 1.8.1.

Thanks in advance.

PS 1: I don't mean two windows literally, it could be a window with two panels/views (for the lack of right word)

PS 2: A lot of similar questions with "multiple windows" talk about multiple viewports. For me it's not necessary - first window is dynamic and the second one is pretty much static.

PS 3: I have a feeling that I must use Ogre GUI's like CEGUI, MyGUI, QuickGUI. Do I really need to ? If yes, please point out the easiest one to start with.

PS 4: This is kindof a [repost](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=78390) from OGRE forum (where I couldn't get an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use Qt for my GUI controls. I think it the most convenient library vor creating non-game GUIs. Combining Ogre and Qt is possible. There are code examples for Windows, Mac, Unix. Please have a look [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=qtOgre).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Even I have found the same after lots of research. Looks like GUI controls are better off when I use Qt or even better with QML. I chose QML + Ogre from [here](http://advancingusability.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/how-to-integrate-ogre3d-into-a-qt5-qml-scene/).